# SONAR FORTIFY plugin import

Tags: sonarqube, fortify

All,
I am trying to get sonar to import fortify analysis report.
I am facing an issue with the code source directory.

My analysis in running on a separate machine and produce a report as follow

```
 <SourceBasePath>C:/STA/Source/src</SourceBasePath>
  <SourceFiles>
    <File size="2409" timestamp="1409914148012" loc="12" type="java" encoding="windows-1252">
      <Name>main/java/com/test/Test/TestRequest.java</Name>
      <LOC type="Fortify">12</LOC>
      <LOC type="Line Count">135</LOC>
      <LOC type="Source Code">57</LOC>
      <LOC type="Comments">59</LOC>
      <LOC type="Comments and Source Code">0</LOC>
      <LOC type="White Space">19</LOC>
```

When the plugin is trying to import it display as follow
[DEBUG] [10:34:42.947] Unable to find "C:/STA/Source/src/main/java/com/test/Test/TestRequest.java". Trying relative path.
[DEBUG] [10:34:42.947] Unable to find "/opt/mount/jenkins/jobs/02-TestFortify/workspace/main/java/com/test/TestRequest.java". Your Fortify analysis...

Looking in the import process code, it first checks for the 
sourceBasePath + vulnerability.getPath()
then for 
base project dir + vulnerability.getPath()

problem, source path are in ${project.build.sourceDirectory} which is different.

I can  think of workaround in building a sym link to the source path before to proceed but I wanted to know if there was any better solution.

Antoine

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that can be useful.  Be aware that you will not get a signed FPR from the result.  This should be fine since you are simply using it for Sonar.

```
import java.io.*;
import com.fortify.io.fvdl.FVDL;
import com.fortify.io.fvdl.FVDLUtil;
import org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLContext;
import com.fortify.ui.model.Project;
import com.fortify.ui.model.util.integration.IntegrationStubFactory;
import com.fortify.ui.model.util.integration.IntegrationUtil;
import com.fortify.ui.model.xml.interfaces.Product;
import com.fortify.util.SystemUtil;

public class FPRMod{
  public static void SetFPRSourceBasePath(String FPRPath, String NewSourceBasePath) throws Exception {
    //Initialize Fortify
    SystemUtil.setInstallRoot();
    IntegrationUtil.initializeFrameworkIntegration(IntegrationStubFactory.getFrameworkIntegrationUtil(), null, false);

    //Load the FPR and FVDL
    Project fpr = IntegrationUtil.loadProjectWithProgress(new File(FPRPath));
    FVDL fvdl = FVDL.unmarshalFVDL(FVDLUtil.getFVDLReader(FPRPath));

    //Set the SourceBasePath in the FPR and FVDL
    fpr.setSourceBasePath(NewSourceBasePath, true);
    fvdl.getBuild().setSourceBasePath(NewSourceBasePath);

    //Save the new FVDL
    fvdl.marshal(new FileWriter(FPRPath + ".mod.fvdl"));

    //Set the FPR to use the new FVDL
    fpr.getProjectInfo(Product.SCA).setEntryName(null);
    fpr.getProjectInfo(Product.SCA).setPath(new File(FPRPath + ".mod.fvdl"));

    //Save the new FPR
    fpr.saveProjectAs(new File(FPRPath + ".mod.fpr"));
  }
}
```